# Specific String input in Java

Tags: java, string, input, syntax-error

I'm making a program that asks for a 5 digit string, containing a letter, then a "-" and 3 numbers.( eG: A-123) I'm using split with the delimiter "-" to split the letter and the numbers, but the whole thing falls apart if the input is different than that exact format. So my question is how to block out any input that doesn't fit with the specific format.

the code I'm using so far:

```
public Room(String Combo) {

   if (Combo.length() == 5){
      String delimiter = "-";
      String[] temp = Combo.split(delimiter);
      long FloorRoomNo = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
      long Floor = FloorRoomNo/100;
      long RoomNo = FloorRoomNo/100;

      this.Floor = (int)Floor;
      this.RoomNo = (int)RoomNo;
      Buildning = temp[0]:
   }else{
      System.err.println("Wrong input length");
      System.exit(-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Check if `Combo.contains(delimiter)` before you make the split. (And please change it to `combo` with lowercase letter)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `String#matches` method to check whether the given input is in a particular pattern. That method takes a regex. You can use it like this: -

```
if (combo.matches("[a-zA-Z]-\\d{3}")) {
    // valid format
}
```

The above `if` condition will return true, if your input string is of the form you described. i.e: -

```
[a-zA-Z]   // Start with a letter
 -         // Followed by a hyphen
\\d{3}     // And then 3 digits.
```

And please follow `Java Naming Convention`. Name your variables starting with lowercase letters.

---

As pointed out in comment, if you use above method, you don't even need to split. You can extract inidividual components, using `capture groups`. So, change the above pattern to: -

```
([a-zA-Z])-(\\d{3})
```

And you have your letter and numbers in *group 1* and *group 2* respectively. But you would have to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes here.

Comment: When doing this there is probably no need for the remaining code anymore, because you could just define and retrieve subgroups instead of tearing the input string apart.